# Can't split the of one coulmn in a python dataframe into two

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-processing

I am having a dataset as following.

```
df=
0    153.38 -27.99
1    151.21 -33.87
2    151.21 -33.87
3    153.05 -26.68
4    153.44 -28.06
Name: merchant_long_lat, dtype: object
```

When I implement the split code for spliting the `lat-long` into two different columns named `lat` and `long` on it i.e.:

```
df[['merch_long','merch_lat']]=df.str.split(expand=True)
```

It returned an error as:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_1821133/1587686441.py in <module>
----> 1 df[['merch_long','merch_lat']]=df.str.split(expand=True)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexers.py in check_key_length(columns, key, value)
    426     if columns.is_unique:
    427         if len(value.columns) != len(key):
--> 428             raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
    429     else:
    430         # Missing keys in columns are represented as -1

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Comment: try, ``df.merchant_long_lat.str.split(expand=True)`` ??

Comment: @Samar does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68524690/12446721) solve your issue? If it solved your issue, don't forget to mark this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do this:

```
df[['merch_long','merch_lat']]=df.merchant_long_lat.str.split(" -",expand=True)
```

You have to specify which column you are trying to split and by what you are splitting. If you aren't specifying by which character/word you want to split then default is " ".

For other information about `pd.Series.str.split()` you can visit [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html).

> String or regular expression to split on. If not specified, split on whitespace.